# Waiting for stream input from child process in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, child-process

My main Node.js process spawns a child process. I want to communicate to the child process by sending it data through its stdin and reading it out from its stdout. The child process will continue running. I want to send it a message, then wait for it to respond, do something with the response, and then continue the main process. How do I best do this? I tried the following:

```
    // I call this function after sending to child's stdin
    private async readWaitStream() {
        let data = '';

        let chunk = '';
        while (chunk = this._child.stdout.read()){
            data += chunk;
        }

        // doesn't finish because child process stays running
        await finished(this._child.stdout); 
        return data;
    }
```

The child process never finishes, and this doesn't work.

Comment: What is `finished`?

Comment: You might want to try `for await (const chunk of this._child.stdout) …`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to solve the problem. I use `once.('readable' ... )`, for example:

```
private readWaitStream() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        let data = '';
        this._child.once('readable', () => {
            let chunk = '';
            while (chunk = this._child.read()) {
                data += chunk;
            }
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
}
```

When I `then` the function, we will wait for input and the promise will only resolve after the next input is available.

Answer (score 0):

Just listen to `end` event of `stdout` then return the data. You need to wrap it into a Promise.

```
  private async readWaitStream() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      let data = '';

      this._child.stdout.on('readable', () => {
        let chunk = '';
        while (chunk = this._child.stdout.read()) {
          data += chunk;
        }
      });

      this._child.stdout.on('end', () => {
        resolve(data); // return data
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Hmm, that didn't seem to work for me. The child process didn't get to end and the promise didn't resolve.

Comment: @XSeven Updated logic. Register listeners in the same time.

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work for me either. It still looks like the child process stdout is never emitting 'end'. The child process must stay running and receive later input. Is there a way to just wait for the child's next response? @hoangdv